# Unable to print post meta value custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin I want to customize. I could add first hand a custom field and was able to add it to post header (added a meta tag).
Now I want to print another custom field along with other data that initially existed in the plugin but I don't succeed in it.
I'm sure the custom field is added to *postmeta* wordpress table with the name I gave; I could get it and print it but I cannot do it where I want to.

Code excerpt is here :

To add the custom field

```
array( 'id' => 'price', 'name' => 'Price:', 'type' => 'text' ),
```

So price is the name of the custom field, and this is a line in the array of custom fields of course. Same line for credit field.

To get the value from postmeta table :

```
$v_credit = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'credit', true );
$v_price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'price', true );
```

Credit was there, I added price.

To print the value :

```
<?php if($v_credit){ ?>
    <?php _e('CREDIT:','mytheme'); ?>
    <div class="course-info"><?php echo $v_credit; ?></div>
<?php }?>
<?php if($v_price){ ?>
    <?php _e('Price:','mytheme');?>
    <div class="course-info"><?php echo $v_price; ?></div>
<?php }?>
```

So credit is showing but not price.
I even tried to print static text but with no success.

Comment: There could be a prefix added by the meta key before its ID that you define, you should check the meta key on the database to know the actual field meta key.

Comment: Thank you silver for your response. But as I said, when I check in the DB everything is as it should be. I could even print the value but not where I need, this is why I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: Is `price` value equal 0 by any chance? Is whole div for price missing or just value itself? Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Thank you Flyer for your help. No the prise is neither empty nor equal to 0. I tried with removing all controls and try to just echo the value with no luck; and the whole div is missing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the key is correct based on the database then your code should work fine unless you added it outside the loop

get a single post ID with  the price value then try this,

```
$x = get_post_meta( 21,'price', true );
echo '<pre>',print_r( $x , 1 ), '</pre>';
```

if it doesn't throw anything then your key is wrong, if it throw something then your above code is outside the loop thus get_the_ID() returns nothings

Comment: nothing is happening, it is like if there's some kind of caching even if I have no caching plugin on my wordpress install. I removed everything, disabled and enabled the plugin, same data was showing...